# Is there any way to automate the testing of flash within web pages using Watir-Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, flash, watir, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am attempting to test several web pages built in Flex, and need to automate clicking on several videos through the Flash interface.  I'm using Ruby and Watir-Webdriver, but I'm not sure how to interact with Flash using them.

Has anyone figured this out?  I've tried using Sikuli, but have found it to be a little clunky and not very fast.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will quote myself:

> It is important to say that Watir CAN NOT control browser plugins like
>   Java applets, Adobe Flash or Microsoft Silverlight.

From https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/about.md

Comment: Is there any other way to automate the interaction of Flash or Flex apps with Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way though. You can embed javascript into your ruby watir script.

It has worked for me

browser.execute_script <<-JS

Global.videoPlayer.sendEvent("play")

JS

Similarly you can do a pause or stop based on the controller on the player

Enjoy !!