# enabling firefox flash with watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, watir

I have been trying unsuccessfully to automate login into a site using firefox that requires flash to be enabled. It works pretty well but ultimately errors out with : "You must have Adobe Flash Player support enabled in your browser.". I've tried just about everything without success. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
ff = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: 'default', 
"acceptInsecureCerts" => true

ff.goto 'https://my.test.site.com/'
ff.driver.manage.window.maximize()

ff.text_field(:id => 'login').set 'mytestuser@domain.com'
ff.text_field(:id => 'password').set 'Password'
ff.button(text: 'Log In').click
```

Comment: Is the whole site flash-based?  Or just some page elements?  `watir` does not support browser-plugins, like Flash and Silverlight.  If you could add additional details about the site-under-test and the exact error message returned, that would help.

Comment: Set it in the `moz:firefoxOptions` `prefs` https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1008#issuecomment-335229523 I'm not adding this as an answer because I don't have the actual Watir code handy to make this work, but you (or someone) should be able to figure out the capabilities for it.

Comment: Yes, the whole site is flash-based. Well, I guess that's that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to automate the testing of flash within web pages using Watir-Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434338/is-there-any-way-to-automate-the-testing-of-flash-within-web-pages-using-watir-w)

Comment: @rickman: You'll have to find another approach then (and I really can't recommend anything unfortunately).  Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!